# What's difference between websocketpp and boost.asio?

Tags: c++, boost-asio, websocket++

Recently I was packaging the Deribit API with websocketpp in C++. But when I read the source code of Websocketpp, I found that it's close linked with boost.asio. I have heard boost.asio before but I don't know that do I need to get a command of boost.asio for the aim of studying websocketpp better. In another word, what's difference between them?

Answer (score 3):

asio provides access to raw tcp and udp sockets, it doesn't implement any application layer protocols.

websocketpp implements the websocket protocol using asio (or various other low level socket libraries)

Comment: oh! Thanks man and one more question: does it mean that if I want to create an app, I don't have to get a good command of Asio and knowing how to use it is enough?

Comment: Yes, if you're only using websockets you probably don't need to know much about asio